# popup and content.js not communicating in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get data from a tab opened with chrome extension. So far my extension can open a new tab with the correct link, but I'm having trouble getting content.js to respond to click on the submit button in my popup window. My entire code is below. I would really appreciate any help.

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function d(c){
        console.log(c)
    }
    $('#rt').click(function(){
        var mov = $('input:text').val()
    //open new link with movie title name
        var movUpdate = mov.replace(/ /g,'_')
        var link = "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/" + movUpdate 
        chrome.tabs.create({"url":link,"selected":false},function(tab){
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{"message":"clicked_submit"}) 

            d(tab.id)
        })
})
})
```

This is my content-js, it is not logging 'popup message'

```
    function d(c){
        console.log(c)
    }
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,sendResponse){
        if(request.message==='clicked_submit'){
            //find the rottentomato scores
            d('popup message')
        }
    });
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
Search RT for Movie: <input type="text" value=""><input type="submit" id="rt">
</div>
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":"extension",
    "version":"0.1",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js":["content.js"]
        }],
    "browser_action":{
                "default_icon":"icon.png",
                "default_popup":"popup.html"
            }
        ,
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions":[
        "tabs"
    ]

}
```

Comment: chrome.tabs.create may invoke the callback before content scripts were injected, there was an answer here that listed the alternative methods like chrome.storage or the background script as a messaging relay. Also, `selected` option is deprecated since Chrome 33 so specify `active: false`.

Comment: do you mind sending me the link to that answer?

Comment: if issue is with chrome.tabs.create, can i use popup js as a messaging relay  instead of background script?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, @wOxxOm is referring to this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). And in addition to what he said, you may want to also include [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) into your list of references wherein it was mentioned that communication between extensions and their content scripts works by using message passing. This related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567038/chrome-extension-sendmessage-from-popup-html-to-content-js-not-working) might also help.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using chrome storage to communicate between tabs. works like a charm

Comment: @st4rgut, Then you should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem. When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://$SITEURL$/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome browser's storage, I figured out how to transfer data between tabs. Content.js scrapes for ratings on the newly opened Rotten Tomatoes tab, stores them using `chrome.storage.local.set` for popup.js to access and display on the active tab.

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function d(c){
        console.log(c)
    }
    $('#rt').click(function(){
        var mov = $('input:text').val()
    //open new link with movie title name
        var movUpdate = mov.replace(/ /g,'_')
        var link = "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/" + movUpdate
        chrome.tabs.create({"url":link,"active":false})

        })

    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, areaName) { //updates the ratings
    // Do whatever you want with the changes.
    console.log('changed!')
    chrome.storage.local.get("keyName",function(items) {
        console.log(items)
        console.log(items.keyName)
        var criticsscore = items.keyName[0]
        var audiencescore = items.keyName[1]
        $('#criticsscore').html('Critics ' + criticsscore)
        $('#audiencescore').html('Audience ' + audiencescore)
        $('#title').html(items.keyName[2])
    // Do something with items.keyName
});
});    

    chrome.storage.local.get("keyName",function(items) {//initialize the application
        console.log(items)
        console.log(items.keyName)
        var critics = items.keyName[0]
        var people = items.keyName[1]
        $('#criticsscore').html('Critics ' + critics)
        $('#audiencescore').html('Audience ' + people)
        $('#title').html(items.keyName[2])

    // Do something with items.keyName
});
})
```

content.js

```
var ratings = document.getElementsByClassName("meter-value")
var critics = ratings[0].innerText
var audienceIndex = ratings.length - 1
var audience = ratings[audienceIndex].innerText
var title = document.getElementById("movie-title").innerText
chrome.storage.local.set({"keyName": [critics,audience,title]},function(){console.log('mah critics stored')});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<style>
    body{
        background-color: red;
        color:white;
    }
    input {
        margin: 2px;
    }
</style>
Search RT for Movie: <input type="text" value=""><input type="submit" id="rt">
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<h3 id="criticsscore"></h3>
<h3 id="audiencescore"></h3>
</div>
```