# Chrome Extension: How to Activate Content Script on an Inactive Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Rotten Tomatoes extension where if you enter the movie name, it will show the critics/audience score. Right now, I am trying to get my background script to communicate with the content script to manipulate the DOM of the opened movie tab. There's a minor problem: content js can only print to the screen when listening for a message set on an active tab.

EDIT: Just to clarify what I wrote above, i'm trying to scrape data from an inactive tab. So far, I'm only able to get script.js to respond in an active tab. I reasoned that in order to scrape a page with chrome api it has to be opened in a tab; however, I don't want the opened tab to interrupt the user's web surfing, hence the inactive tab. If someone has an easier way to go about doing this I'm all ears.

background.js (this works)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,sendResponse){
        if(request.message==="clicked_browser_action"){

            chrome.tabs.query({"active":true, "currentWindow":true},function(tabs){
                console.log(tabs)
                var activeTab = tabs[0];
                console.log(activeTab)
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message":"message2Tab"})
            })
        }
    })
```

but not this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,sendResponse){
        if(request.message==="clicked_browser_action"){

            chrome.tabs.query({"currentWindow":true},function(tabs){
                var activeTab = tabs[tabs.length-1]; //find last tab
                console.log(activeTab)
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message":"message2Tab"})
            })
        }
    })
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('started')
    if( request.message === "message2Tab" ) {
    console.log('started')

    }
  }
);
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
Search RT for Movie: <input type="text" value=""><input type="submit" id="rt">
</div>
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":"extension",
    "version":"0.1",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js":["content.js"]
        }],
    "browser_action":{
                "default_icon":"icon.png",
                "default_popup":"popup.html"
            }
        ,
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions":[
        "tabs"
    ]

}
```

I posted the full code in an [earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928112/popup-and-content-js-not-communicating-in-chrome-extension?noredirect=1#comment71038504_41928112). Many thanks for your help so far

Comment: I don't need to see the console output  ,  i just want to retrieve text from that page

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: OK I updated my question in case it wasn't clear what I was asking for before

Comment: just posted it, thanks

Comment: I ran into the same problem with an extension i'm developing. Did you find a solutions eventually?

Comment: i never figured it out, but i found a workaround. see answer below: my code is on github too: https://github.com/st4rgut22/rottenremoval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used chrome storage to communicate between tabs:

content.js

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"keyName": [critics,audience,title]},function(){console.log('mah critics stored')});
```

popup.js

```
  chrome.storage.local.get("keyName",function(items) {
        console.log(items)
        console.log(items.keyName)
        var criticsscore = items.keyName[0]
        var audiencescore = items.keyName[1]
        $('#criticsscore').html('Critics ' + criticsscore)
        $('#audiencescore').html('Audience ' + audiencescore)
        $('#title').html(items.keyName[2])
    // Do something with items.keyName
});
});    

    chrome.storage.local.get("keyName",function(items) {//initialize the application
        console.log(items)
        console.log(items.keyName)
        var critics = items.keyName[0]
        var people = items.keyName[1]
        $('#criticsscore').html('Critics ' + critics)
        $('#audiencescore').html('Audience ' + people)
        $('#title').html(items.keyName[2])

    // Do something with items.keyName
});
```